# Copying a list of folders with copytree

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small script that will copy a users folders to a networked drive when for when they move to a new PC.

```
import os, sys, shutil

user = input("Enter user name: ")
copyfolders = ['Desktop','Documents','Favorites']


shutil.copytree(os.path.join("C:", "Users", user, 
*copyfolders),os.path.join("L:", user , "backup"))
```

The issue I'm having is getting the script to do one folder directory at a time currently it's appending all folder names like so:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:Users\\user\\Desktop\\Documents\\Favorites'
```

I'm not sure how to get this into a loop however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `copytree` command for each folder

```
for folder in copyfolders:
  shutil.copytree(os.path.join("C:", "Users", user, folder),os.path.join("L:", user , "backup"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, sys, shutil

user = input("Enter user name: ")
copyfolders = ['Desktop','Documents','Favorites']

for folder in copyfolders:
    shutil.copytree(os.path.join("C:", "Users", user, folder), os.path.join("L:", user , "backup"))
```